# Where exactly should I put \enlargethispage command to make a long footnote all stay on the same page? Before the footnote?

Tags: footnotes

Where exactly should I put `\enlargethispage` command to get a long footnote on the same page? before the footnote?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you want to put it anywhere at the top level (not inside a box) that lands on the page you want to affect. The earlier the better.